# Is it ok to restart a BackgroundWorker inside its Completed event

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I want a background worker to continue running and occasionally update the user interface. My first idea was to use a BackgroundWorker and in its completed event just fire it up again.

**Is using a BackgroundWorker in this fashion acceptable?**  Or are there potential issues from using the completed event to trigger the worker?

---

Below is some Pseudo code of what my intentions are

```
class Program
{
    private static BackgroundWorker worker;
    private static Int32 runs = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(runs);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Do time consuming work
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }

    static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Update the UI and start time consuming work again
        runs++;
        Console.WriteLine("Completed run #" + runs);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not absolutely clear from the spec whether a BackgroundWorker could be considered to be still *running* when the RunWorkerCompleted event is triggered - in which case calling RunWorkerAsync() will cause an exception.

Because the spec is unclear I wouldn't re-use the BackgroundWorker object: it might work or it might break on different releases of .Net. Just create a new one in the worker_RunWorkerCompleted() handler.

If you search for *BackgroundWorker reuse*, you will find several posts suggesting there might be some issues in this area.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Backgroundworker in this fashion is not acceptable.  That's why it specifically has a ProgressChanged event.  I would suggest rewriting your app to accept a MaxRuns integer and pass that once to the BGW.  Then inside the BGW worker loop over each run.  At the bottom of each run, you then report progress.

I know your example is a shortened and is a console app.  But in case you ever have a forms app, you could set up a progress bar from 0 - MaxRuns, and have the BGW worker report it's progress back to the UI so the UI can move the progress bar.

On last tip: progress reporting has a parameter named ProgressPercentage.  It is just an int, which can be negative or > 100.  So don't feel constrained between 0 and 100.

EDIT: Example Code

```
class Program
```

{
    private static BackgroundWorker worker;
    private static Int32 maxRuns = 3333;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(maxRuns);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int totalRuns = (int)e.Argument;
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRuns; i++)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        //Do time consuming work 
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        worker.ReportProgress(i, sw.Elapsed);
    }
}

// This method runs in the foreground thread while the background worker is busy.
static void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.ProgressPercentage is not a true percentage.  Rather it is the Run number.
    var percent = (100 * e.ProgressPercentage) / maxRuns;
    var elapsed = (TimeSpan)e.UserState;
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}% complete.  Run {1} of {2} took {3}.", percent, e.ProgressPercentage, maxRuns, elapsed));
}

static void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Background Completed.");
}
```

}

Comment: I like your idea of using the Progress Changed event but I am particularly interested in the WorkerCompleted event and if there are any particular problems with using it, and if there are problems what are they.

Comment: I can only encourage you to use the BGW in a proper fashion.  If you step back to look at the big picture of what you're application is trying to do, hopefully you will realize the ProgressChanged event is a classic fit.

Comment: @GER But the ProgressChanged event is exactly the semanitcs you're looking for; why try to hammer WorkerCompleted to be something its not?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to restart it immediately, it would seem to be a better option to just wrap the DoWork function body in an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run the code... It will throw an exception saying:

```
This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently.
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(Object argument)
at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
```

So it is even not possible.